# Adsense SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, adsense, ads

After reading over the [Adsense SDK for iOS docs](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/ios/) I'd like to actually download the SDK. **Where can I find it?**

After some searching I came across some [sample projects](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/) from Google. However they all seem to use the AdMob SDK which I'd rather not use since it adds 10+ Mb to the size of my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adsense SDK [moved](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/). It's now called Google AdMob Ads SDK. Here is the [downloads](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download) page.

Comment: The iOS AdMob SDK is 10 Mb. Is this really the only option? I just downloaded a 2 Mb app from the app store that's displaying DoubleClick ads. Perhaps it's using an older SDK.

Comment: Perhaps the SDK comes with sample projects.

Comment: Unfortunately no sample projects. The docs just say include everything in your project except the readme. This increases the size of my app by about 10 Mb which isn't so great.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. That's a different topic.

Comment: Chris you're right about just using the Admob SDK. Turns out it doesn't increase the app size too much.

Comment: The Google AdMob Ads SDK is not compatible with the current Google AdSense for Mobile Apps SDK when used in conjunction with AdWhirl.